# How to retain the previous state of Viewer Toolbar

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have one custom toolbar buttons for the viewing 2d files. Clicking on same opens the panel for selecting file for comparison and loads the 'PixelCompare' extension. Once the operation is done, and when I click the 'Exit Comparing' toolbar button of PixelCompare, it doesn't show that extra custom toolbar button. Please suggest what is required. How can I handle the inbuilt extension unload. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Maybe a picture showing where you are placing the button and how it disappears?

Comment: Got this resolved. Accidently created two instances of the viewer and thus the new instance was overriding the  previous settings.

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting us know! 